# It is posible make Mobile view without Appbar?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

it is posible great login view wthout AppBar and after login show it?
this is my app design.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the `AppBar`, like any other JavaFX Node:

```
appBar.setManaged(false);
appBar.setVisible(false);
```

If you are extending a Gluon Mobile `View`, you can override `updateAppBar` to do so:

```
@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setManaged(false);
    appBar.setVisible(false);
}
```

You can find more about this at the [documentation](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/#_the_appbar).